# Connect to SQL Server behind NAT from remote machine through Server

Tags: sql-server, server, rdp, hole-punching

First of all I am very new to this so sorry if I mess up.

[I have the following setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5ppV.png).

A Client with SQL Server 2014, a Windows Server 2012 and my Remote Machine Device. The objective is to, from the PC/Laptop/Android, access the Clients Database.

The Client is blocked by a restrictive firewall, all inbound ports are blocked apart from the usual few, but all outbound ports are open.

I have been told that from the remote machine I have to be able to start a Remote Desktop connection to the server on a specific port (XXXX) with a specific Username and Password and have the server port forward it to the client.

After searching for similar problems I have seen solutions like Socat, Netcat, Teamviewer, etc. to get a connection through the Firewall but am not entierly sure where to start.

I'm sorry if I haven't worded this correctly,
Thank you